# WSO2 Stream Processor No Extension Exists for

Tags: wso2, stream-processing

I installed WSO2 Stream Processor on Windows 8 but when I import any example from "Import Sample" menu of Stream Processor Studio, it reports the error message "No extension exist for...."
for any sink or source.
Can anyone help me please?

[img example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwsqY.png)

Thanks

Emiliano

Comment: Please provide the version of WSO2 Stream Processor you are using.

Comment: The WSO2 Stream processor Version I'm using is 4.3.0